# I'm having trouble trying to open jupyter notebook

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm starting to work on Anaconda and I can´t open the jupyter notebook.
When I try it, it gives out a application launch error, saying the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pc\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 47, in 
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from 'zmq.backend.cython' (C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, you can give it a try:

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
```

then:

```
pip install pyzmq
```

**I run these commands on anaconda prompt**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with both jupyter notebook and spyder.

My way to fix this:

1. Uninstall anaconda and python3.7(or whichever version you have installed)
2. Delete "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python" Python folder
3. Reinstall anaconda

Then, from anaconda prompt, write

```
jupyter notebook
```

or

```
spyder
```

That's it. Hope it works